# How can I send logs to the main screen of OSX Console?

Tags: macos, logs, console

As an application developer, how can I send logs so that they appear on the main screen of Console, i.e. when I select the name of my computer under "Devices?"

[image: Selecting my computer under "Devices"]

So far, I have successfully sent logs to:

- "Log Reports" under "Reports" by writing a log file within `~/Library/Logs/`
- "system.log" under "Reports" by sending logs with syslog using RFC 3164

I'm currently on MacOS Catalina 10.15.1 with Console 1.1 (4.0.15).

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not actively coding under macOS, I would say with some reservation: This might be worth reading:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging